# Unwanted vertical whitespace when using fill between in pgf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

In this instance of using `fill between` with `pgfplots`, I get 3 or 4 inches of unwanted vertical whitespace. Commenting out the `fill between` removes the whitespace.

I have not encountered this before. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Even more bizarre... if I change the function in the code below to 6*x^2, the problem disappears! It seems that having a function with two terms makes the problem appear. This seems to point to `pgfplots` (or at least the way my system interacts with `pgfplots`) as the culprit.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,graphicx}
\textwidth=7.0in
\textheight=9.5in
\voffset=-1.25in
\hoffset=-1.25in

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
    ,axis lines=middle
    ,axis line style={-latex}
    ,samples=100,
    %,grid
    ,thick
    ,domain=0:3
    ,xtick={0,1,2,3,4}
    ,ytick={0,9}
    ,xmin=-.5
    ,xmax=3.5
    ,ymin=-3
    ,ymax=7
    %,xlabel shift={1in}
    %,y tick label style={yshift={5pt}}
    %,legend pos=outer north east
    ]
    \addplot[name path=f,domain=0:4,black,thick,no marks] {6*x^2-2*x^3-2};
    \draw[<->,thick] (0.75,6) -- (3.25,6);
    \node at (2,6)[above] {$(2,6)$};
    \draw[black,fill=black] (2,6) circle (1.5pt);
    \path[name path=axis] (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \node at (1.5,-2) {$p(x)=ax^2-2x^3+b$};
    \addplot [
        thick,
        smooth,
        color=black,
        fill=gray,
        fill opacity=0.3
    ]
    fill between[
        of=f and axis,
        soft clip={domain=0:2}
    ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue when I compile your code on an updated TeXLive installation. Maybe you only need to update your TeX installation.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I updated all components of my MikTeX installation and the problem remains...

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for a MikTeX user who is able to reproduce this. (Usually there are no differences between TeXLive and MikTeX.)

Comment: With recent version of MiTeX your MWE work fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because with recent LaTeX installation the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation for why this works, but this did resolve the issue so I wanted to post it in case it helps someone else:

I simply removed `domain=0:4` from the first `\addplot` and the problem disappeared.

```
\addplot[name path=f,black,thick,no marks] {6*x^2-2*x^3-2};
```